# requests.patch() returns 200 OK but nothing changes

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests

I'm trying to use the `requests` module and the MailChimp API to update my contacts to "subscribed." As per the [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/#Update_a_contact), I need to make a `requests.patch()` request using an MD5 hash of the member's email (lowercase). The code I've developed to do this with an email list is as follows:

```
import json
import requests
import hashlib

api_link = 'https://us6.api.mailchimp.com' 
post_endpoint = '/3.0/lists/%s/members/' % (listID) # List ID is in my code
email_dict = {
    'status': 'subscribed'
    }
email_json = json.dumps(email_dict)

for email in email_list:
  hashed = hashlib.md5(email.encode()).hexdigest()
  print(api_link+post_endpoint+hashed)
  response = requests.patch(api_link+post_endpoint+hashed,
                           json=email_json,
                           auth=('me',api_key)
                           )
  print(email)
  print(response.status_code, response.reason)
```

This code prints a response `status_code` and `reason` of `200 OK`, which means (as far as I can tell) that something is going through. But the email remains unsubscribed. Since the JSON seems to be correct, and the link structure matches the documentation, what else is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this format:

```
payload={'status': 'subscribed'}

headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}

requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Sorry, you are using an API, i also checked your md5 and it's okay, i made a bad assumption, but in your request: requests.patch(api_link, post_endpoint+hashed,
                           json=email_json
                           ) shouldn't be api_link + post_endpoint + hashed to concatenate the link? and on your post_endpoint i think you need to put a slash '/' so the link is formatted correctly

Comment: I combined them but to no effect. Regarding the ending '/', the documentation doesn't seem to indicate that's necessary. Right now, the URL prints as `https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{listID}/members/{memberID}`.

Comment: try with this format requests.patch(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers) and on headers put headers={'content-type': 'application/json'} see if it works

Comment: It worked when I updated the headers and switched it to `data`, like you suggested, thanks. Edit it into your answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: glad i helped, i'm currently working on a python server and i had a lot of issues on data formatting, it seems you are converting to json your email_dict, then passing it on the request parameter json, i think the json parameter on requests automatically converts a dict into json, try to pass your e-mail dict directly without converting to json to that parameter and tell me if it works. that might be the reason why when you pass as data parameter it works because data is plain-text with an encoding

Comment: It needed the header to identify the content type as JSON, but it doesn't recognize the data in the dict.